# Remove cycles in the path of moving agents

Tags: list, netlogo

I have a list of link nodes which is collected by a `walker` agent during his motion on links.
When he reaches a destination he has to save his path but without loops.

A method to eliminate loops is by iteratively scanning the link position by position starting from the source link: for the link at the `i-th` position, the path is scanned starting from the destination link until the first occurrence of the link is encountered, say, at position `j` (it always holds that `i <= j` because the scanning process stops at position `i` at the latest). If we have `j > i`, the subpath of links from position `i+1` to position `j` corresponds to a loop and can be eliminated.

[image: Scanning process for loop elimination]

I have been trying to code a recursive `to-report` which takes the initial list  as argument without success. The code of my tests which gives me the loop but not the path without the loop is this:

```
to-report no-cycles [ lista ]
  ifelse empty? lista [
    report lista ] [
    let x1 (first lista)
    let rest (butfirst lista)
    let rev-rest (reverse rest)
    let rev-rest1 (first rev-rest)
    ifelse x1 != rev-rest1 [
      report no-cycles (butlast rest)
    ] [
      report lista ]
 ]
end
```

I do not know if this is a good approach.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please share what you have tried, and how it was deficient.

Comment: Above is the code I was trying to make it work, but for a list of numbers (not links) gives me the loop but not the path without the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to make your coded approach work exactly, but your general concept makes sense. The code below is a `to-report` that accepts a list and iterates backwards through it, comparing all items preceding the current item to the current item. If there is a match, it jumps to the earliest instance of that item. Note that I was testing this with lists of links and numbers, so it should remove duplicate items in any type of list. However, it does return a list so if you input a list of links it will *not* return an agentset- if you want to have the links do something you have to use `foreach "your-list"` rather than `ask`. If all you need is the list, the code below should at least get you started.

```
to-report no-cycles [ input_list ]

  ifelse empty? input_list [
    report input_list
  ]
  [
    let final_list []
    let temp_list reverse input_list 
    let n 0

    while [ n < length temp_list] [
      let x n
      let cur item n temp_list
      while [ x < length temp_list ] [
        if (item x temp_list) = cur  [
          set n x          
        ]
        set x x + 1
      ]
      set final_list fput (item n temp_list) final_list
      set n n + 1
    ]
    report final_list
  ]

end
```

**Edits below**

Once you have your list of links, you can use a `foreach` to iterate through the list and do what you like. For example, if you wanted each link in the list to increase a variable by one, you could use the code block below.

```
to-report modify-links-in-list [ input_list_of_links ]  

  ;;; input must be a list of links, not an agentset
    foreach input_list_of_links [
    [x] -> 
    ask x [
      set example_var example_var + 1
    ]
  ]

  report input_list_of_links  
end
```

This will modify the variables of the links themselves, so inspect one of the links that you'd expect to change to monitor that it is working properly. Hope that is what you're after!

Comment: Thank you very much.I am passing a list of links to this `no-cycle` procedure and it returns a list of links too. However, after removing the loops I must increment the value of a variable associated with each link in the path, so I think it would be a better to return a set of agents (`path-links`) so I could make something like `ask path-links [add-value-to-links]`. It is possible with this procedure or I must use `foreach`?. I have tested `foreach` to add a value to each link that returns `no-cycle` but gives me error. Thank you.

Comment: All the issues comes because to eliminate loops I must use a list of links. I think I would have less trouble if I could remove loops using a links agentset. The problem is that if I do `set path (link-set path new-link)` I would alter the path followed by the agent because it will eliminate duplicates and I could loose some links, isn't it?

Comment: Using this procedure I don't think you can return an agentset, unfortunately. However, if all you need to do is get the list of links to modify one of their variables, you can certainly do so using a `foreach`. See my edited answer for an example.